# Azure DevOps - Assign multiple products to a work item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm new to DevOps, so I'm trying to figure out all the logic. Our work organization is very simple:

- We are only a small team of developers.
- We develop several software which are interrelated (the software communicate together when they are running, they share code via git submodules...).
- All team members can work on any software.
- We want to have one place for work items, that's why we only created one DevOps project.
- We don't want to work with sprints or any other advanced agile functionality.
- **We would like to be able to indicate in a work item which software (one or more) are concerned by the work item.**

The last point is where I start to get lost... Can someone advise me how to do this? I created a "zones path" (one per software) but I can only assign one zone path per work item, so it doesn't work...

Comment: Here we use tags. Simple solution but effective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I also thought about this solution but correct me if I am wrong, you have to write the tag(s) name(s) each time you create a work item? You can't have it as a selection list?

Comment: Oh I can see that there is a suggestion list with the previously used tag! So it could do the job pretty well! :) I am open to any other suggestion thought ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you can add a custom field(Picklist and Multi-value ) to work item type in **Organization Settings -> Process**.

Then you can select the values in work item to define the softwares.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Install the extension: [Multivalue control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control) to your organization.

Step2: Create Inherited process in **Organization Settings-> Process**.

Step3: Select the target work item type and edit the work item.

Step4: Create a new custom field and define it as Picklist.

For example:

[image]

Step5: Change the field as Multi-value field with the extension: Multivalue control.

Click the **Add custom control** option.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]